# Count a list of specific strings in an R data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe, count, unique

I have a data frame with 5 columns, but I am interested in one column "Conditions". Within **conditions** column, I need to find a way to count the number of specific entries in a cell. Each column cell can have one entry or more than one entry separated by **( , )** . So my data frame looks something like

```
S.NO                   Conditions
11            Eye Color 
12            Sound of your voice
13            Certain disease,Size of a palm,Eye Color
16            Eye Color,Hair color
17            Hair color,Height
18            Sound of your voice,Height
```

I want to **count** all the differnt **entries/string** at once.  Total I have 35 list of different string in **Conditions** column and I want my Output something like this.

**OUTPUT**

```
Eye color   Sound of your voice   Certain disease    Size of a palm    Hair color   Height
    3           2                      1                   1              2          2
```

Comment: Try this: `table(unlist(strsplit(df$Conditions, ', ')))`

Comment: @Sotos This one works perfect only for single entry. More than one entry by comma separated is not working with table function

Comment: What do you mean? I get the correct result. Note you have two `Eye color` and one `Eye Color` (capital `C`)

Comment: @Sotos I corrected my mistakes. Yes I pasted my data strings with a space after a comma. I removed the space after comma in your first comment and yes it works now.  You can answer to my question as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i do not know the exact structure of the data, i assumed the data to be as below

### data

```r
data <- tribble(
~Conditions, ~value,
'Eye color', '3',
'Sound of your voice', '2',
'Certain disease, Size of a palm, Eye color', '1,1,2',
'Eye color, Hair color', '2,2',
'Hair color, Height', '3,1',
'Sound of your voice, Height', '1,4'
)
```

for the above data we can write the below code to get the expected result

### code

```r
library(tidyverse)

Conditions <- unlist(strsplit(data$Conditions,','))
value <- unlist(strsplit(data$value,','))


df <- bind_cols(Conditions,value) %>% setNames(c('Conditions', 'value')) %>% 
mutate(across(everything(), ~trimws(.x)), value=as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  arrange(Conditions) %>% group_by(Conditions) %>% slice_head(n=1) %>% 
mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Conditions, values_from =value)
```

### output

```r
# A tibble: 1 × 7
    row `Certain disease` `Eye color` `Hair color` Height `Size of a palm` `Sound of your voice`
  <int>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>            <dbl>                 <dbl>
1     1                 1           3            2      1                1                     2
```

Comment: There are no values, I want to count the same string . You can check the data and its output which is clearly mentioned in the question. Thanks

Comment: I updated the code as per your comment, hope it works, could you please confirm